# Print as PDF functionality in Contacts module

Tags: pdf, sugarcrm

I am using Sugar Enterprise 6.4.0
Is there any way to Add "Print as PDF" like functionality available in Quotes module to the Contacts module. I want to save the contact information into a PDF format by clicking on a button that may appear in the Contact module Detail View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question but thought would post a related reply, might help out someone.

In the `Contacts module` there is a `Generate Letter` option in the actions dropdown on detail view. This option will link to the related templates you create in `PDF Templates` module.

If you do not have a pre-defined template, you can go to the PDF Templates module build a custom template for the related module with the information you need in the PDF.

Then when you click on the Generate Letter link, it will show you the templates present for the said module, you just have to select the preferred template and it will download the PDF for you.

If I've understood your question correctly this I think might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Synolia PDF Manager....

http://www.sugarforge.org/projects/synopdfmanager/

Comment: Isn't it possible to copy the functionality of Quotes module in Contacts module. If possible can you give me some tips.

Comment: It's not that trivial at all. I'd recommend the above addon that is easier to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply i have installed Synolia but i think that it is not compatible with our Sugar version which is Sugar Professional Versione 6.1.1 (Build 5512) but on Synolia module page the version compatiblity shows "Sugar Versions : Version 5.5" is it  means i can not use this module in my Sugar Pro 6.1.1 Another thing for your kind information is this that i have downloaded the PDF Manager for SugarCRM 6.0 "SynoPDFManager 20101117.zip" and load it with module loader but no "PDF" button appears anywhere which needs to be, as shown in screenshots on the Synolia module page. Help!

Comment: You should reach out to Synolia directly; I think this listing is out of date as the add-on is compatible with 6.1.1